# How to take the derivative of a summation with respect to the number of terms?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, derivatives

Suppose I have a function defined as:

$$f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

where $x_i\sim\text{Uniform(0,1)}$. Suppose, there is a random seed for sampling, such that for a given $n$, the sequence of numbers $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ is deterministic.

How should one go about calculating $\frac{df}{dn}$?

Comment: The sum is only well-defined for $n\in\mathbb N$ but to take a derivative it would have to well-defined for $n\in\mathbb R$ (or at least $n\in U\subset\mathbb R$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Makes sense. I also realized that this is not well defined.

Comment: maybe you should try to describe the original problem that you were trying to solve